# Can anyone explain me how is this a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicates

[Ubuntu Touchscreen on Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro](https://askubuntu.com/q/375489/169736)

> Does anyone have any experience with Ubuntu running on the Yoga 2 Pro in terms of the functionality of the touchscreen?

I really, really, don't see how this can be a duplicate, so I ask them here how can a totally opinion based question "what is your experience using X?" with something like:

> How can I disable the touchpad automatically when I turn the monitor on the back?

A plea for sanity. This is not a duplicate!

Comment: It is relevant to [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/367963/ubuntu-on-lenovo-yoga-2-pro) - but probably a not a duplicate as this is about the touchscreen not just the computer in general.

Comment: @Wilf and that one is totally open ended.

Comment: For anyone wondering, here's the second question's url: http://askubuntu.com/questions/450066/rotate-touchscreen-and-disable-the-touchpad-on-yoga-2-pro-in-rotated-mode and I totally agree this isn't a duplicate.